# Member access rules for friend of derived class, where the naming class is the base class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

<sub>*All standard references below refer, unless noted otherwise, to [N4861 (March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

**Background**

According to [[class.access.base]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#5):

> If a base class is accessible, one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class [...].

Meaning the following example is well-formed:

```
class N {};

class P : private N {
    friend void f();
};

void f()  { 
    P p{};
    N* n = &p; // R: OK as per [class.access.base]/5
}
```

as `N` is an accessible base class at `R` above<sup>(+)</sup>.

[class.access.base]/5 also mentions that [**emphasis** mine]:

> The access to a member is affected by the class in which the member is
> named. **This naming class is the class in which the member name was
> looked up and found**. [ *Note:* [...] If both a class member access
> operator and a qualified-id are used to name the member (as in
> `p->T​::​m`), the class naming the member is the class denoted by the
> nested-name-specifier of the qualified-id (that is, `T`). — *end note*
> ]

and [**emphasis** mine]:

> A member `m` is accessible at the point `R` **when named in class** `N` if
>
> - [...]
> - /5.3 `m` as **a member of** `N` **is protected**, and `R` occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or in a member of a class `P` derived
>   from `N`, where `m` as a member of `P` is public, private, or
>   protected, or
> - /5.4 there exists a base class `B` of `N` that is accessible at `R`, and `m` is accessible at `R` when named in class `B`.

With that in mind, consider the following example:

```
class N {
  protected:
    int m;
};

class P : private N {
    friend void f();
};

void f()  {
    P p{};
    (&p)->N::m = 42;  // R: #1
}
```

where as per above the *naming class* at `#1` is `N`. The example is accepted by both Clang and GCC, for various compiler versions and standards, meaning it's arguably well-formed.

It would seems as if `&p` (which is of type `P*`) is implicitly converted to `N*` (fulfilling [[class.access.base]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#6)), but I'm wondering by what rules the member `m` of `N` (`N` being the naming class) is accessible at an `R` which is a friend to a derived class `P` of `N`.

**Question**

- What rule(s) governs that `#1` is well-formed?

As per above, the *naming class* at `#1` is `N`, but [[class.access.base]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#5.3) should not apply as `R` is *in a friend* of class `P` derived from `N` (/5.3 only mentions *in a member* of class `P`). [[class.access.base]/5.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#5.4) should not apply as the naming class is `N` which is the top-level class in the class hierarchy.

We may note that [[class.protected]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.protected#1) mentions the very example above as well-formed as part of the non-normative example block of the paragraph. However, [class.protected]/1 in its entirety is described as

> An additional access check [...]

arguably meaning [class.access.base] still needs to apply; it particularly seems as if [class.access.base]/5.3 is arguably missing mentioning the case "or a friend of class `P`" which [class.protected]/1 shows in an (non-normative) example.

---

(+) An accessible base class

In the following example:

```
class B { };

class N : B {
    friend void f();
};

void f()  { /* R */ }
```

according to [[class.access.base]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#4), specifically [[class.access.base]/4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.access.base#4.2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A base class `B` of `N` is accessible at `R`, if
>
> - /4.1 [...]
> - /4.2 `R` **occurs in a** member or **friend of class** `N`, and an invented public member of `B` would be a private or protected member
>   of `P`, [...]

`B` is accessible at `R`, namely in the friend `f` of `N`.

Comment: It appears to me that `class N{ protected: int m;};class P:private N{ void fun(){ N& rf = *this; rf.m = 1;} };` where `rf.m = 1` should be wellf-formed as per [class.access.base#5.3], since R is in the **member function** of P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the section [class.protected#1] is an additional clause for [class.access.base#5] when the nominated member is a protected member of the **naming class** to which R occurs at a member or friend of a derived class.
According to [class.access.base#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#1),
the non-static protected member of `N` is accessible as a private member of the derived class `P`. We are permitted to access the member `m` in a friend of `P` as per [class.access.base#5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.access.base#5.2), if the naming class is `P`

> m as a member of N is private, and R occurs in a member or friend of class N, or

Back to [class.protected#1], we should take a look at the following rule:

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause [class.access] is applied when a **non-static data member or non-static member function** is a **protected member of its naming class** ([class.access.base])115 As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class C.

In other words, the rule says that only if these conditions are satisfied will the additional rule be applied. That is:

> 1. The member should first be a **non-static** member(data or function)
> 2. The member should be a protected member of the naming class.

In order to make the additional rule apply, the following conditions should also be satisfied

> 3. As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a **friend or member of some class C**.
> 4. If the access is to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), the nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a class derived from C.
> 5. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression. In this case, the class of the object expression shall be C or a class derived from C.

Condition 3 might have some confusion, however, it does not say `C` must be the naming class or not. It just says that the member can be accessible in a member or friend of `C`.

After sorting out these conditions, we could take a look at the example

```cpp
void f()  {
    P p{};
    (&p)->N::m = 42;  // R: #1
}
```

The naming class is N and the non-static member `m` is a protected of `N`, hence conditions 1 and 2 are true.

`m` as a private member is accessible in a friend of `P`, hence condition 3 is true.

`(&p)->N::m` is a class member access expression where its object expression is of type P, hence condition 5 is true. So, such an expression is well-formed when it occurs in `f`.

If change the non-static member `m` to be a static member, then condition 1 is false, which means the additional rule will not apply to the expression.

In simple, [class.protected#1] add an extra option(that is a friend) for the latter bullet of [class.access.base#5.2], if these conditions are satisfied. Moreover, it also restricts these members that might be accessible as per the latter bullet of [class.access.base#5.2] to turn non-accessible members when they satisfy these conditions.