# Can a method be referenced using a child class name in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Please consider a struct `A` with a method `f`, and an inherited struct `B`, which does not redefine `f`. In this case `B::f` refers to the same method as `A::f`.

Is it allowed to invoke the method `f` of an `A` object using `B::f` name as in the following example?

```
struct A { void f() {} };
struct B : A {};
int main() { A{}.B::f(); }
```

Clang and GCC diverge here. Clang is fine with the program, while GCC prints the error:

```
error: 'B' is not a base of 'A'
```

demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pn7jehzdP

Which compiler is right here according to the standard?

Comment: For some extra confusion, it stops accepting the code when `B` has its own `f()`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/shEKEvY6j. I wonder if this is an extension of straight up non-conformance.

Comment: Related: [Member access rules for friend of derived class, where the naming class is the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905923/member-access-rules-for-friend-of-derived-class-where-the-naming-class-is-the-b).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**GCC** is correct: [class.access.base]/6 requires that a pointer to the left-hand operand of `.` be able to be

> implicitly converted to a pointer to the naming class of the right operand.

The term "naming class" is defined in [class.access.general]/5; in your example it is `B`, and obviously an `A*` cannot be **implicitly** converted to a `B*`.

The placement of the rule is counterintuitive for this particular case that has no non-public members or inheritance.

Comment: Doesn't just https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.id#general-2.1 apply?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: What’s “the member’s class”?  The closest neighboring case seems to be pointers to members, which use the base class even when written as `&B::f`.

Comment: _What’s “the member’s class”?_ This is what I would also like to know. Also, the rule is prolly meant to be diagnosable, so it shall use «shall» instead of «can».

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Presumably, *member's class* refers to the class of which the member denoted by an id-expression is a direct member.

Comment: @DavisHerring It seems that GCC is a kind of coincident to reject that example. Consider this example https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8a4KWceMj, GCC seems not to implement [basic.lookup.qual#general-3];  *If nothing is found by qualified lookup for a member-qualified name that is the terminal name ([expr.prim.id.unqual]) of a nested-name-specifier and is not dependent, it undergoes unqualified lookup.*

Comment: @xmh0511: I don’t see how you conclude that: GCC is obviously *finding* `::B`, but it’s rejecting because there’s no way to use it successfully there.

Comment: @DavisHerring I meant, `struct A { 
    enum C{
        f = 0
    };
};
struct B : A {

};
int main() { 
    auto v = A{}.B::f; 
}` should be well-formed, since `f` is neither non-static data member nor non-static member function. However, GCC reported *'B' is not a base of 'A'*, I suspected that GCC didn't support [basic.lookup.qual#general-3]

Comment: @xmh0511: That sounds like a Core issue (although I don’t know what would be the preferred resolution).

Comment: @DavisHerring  How do you think about this example. Do you prefer that the example should be well-formed or ill-formed?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it allowed to invoke the method f of an A object using B::f name as
> in the following example?
>
> struct A { void f() {} };
>
> struct B : A {};
>
> int main() { A{}.B::f(); }

`A{}.B::f()` tries to build an object of type `A`. Then call its member `B::f` This the error, because A knows nothing about B.

If you want to call a base member from a derived class them normally you just use `D d;` `d.f();`

In your case, use `B{}.A::f()`

Be aware that calling a base method like this will break virtual ways.