# Code that Clang compiles but failed on GCC, is the code well-defined according to standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[godbot](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbsgsTAQIh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHCgT4ggB0FxtXt/cMOy8%2B0Obicr2ImFYl2ud1u4K8Dj2FgOAHYrLc9gA3PCNLxiLGoPDoPb8VAQOao9E3PY017oEAoJYEZ5uEEHMyWBmk8xmFlsukM1y0Q5U1EAERhJhREo2VJh8MRYpAyKlculIslt1CzNOoQg2r2DWAyFIe2QCAaACpDcRgJiTABWKwOsUU1Uwmli63Ew5ivZhADuezF5I1GL2rzOeGQAH1RK8QRZLZcIOg5gBaS5KkCk0Oyj17LD0AhPdBhu7q24cBa0TgO3h%2BDhaUioTisyzWCNLFZPTY8UgETTVhYAa388Q%2Bki4DvikjMAE5JA6zFwNvP9JxJA2hy3OLwFCANAOhws4LAkGgWEk6LFyJRL9f6HFgFwNFw%2BHQS8QDxAojuoqEDQAJ47pebCCAA8gwtAgU2vBYKcRjiHBpD4BCNSYpgB4oZgqjVF4JY7tqmC1twvC0HgUTEMBHhYDuBDEHgLCcDwCxUAYwAKAAangmABhBSSMCxvD8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOoKG6O%2BBhGCg1jWPolEHrAzBsCAMQAggpzECOpCYXE3CSFocwLKgSSOAI2H7iR1T2X4ECuKMfhLoEDDoL0JRlCAGx5GkrmeSA3kpKFGT%2Bf0cTBe0rldCMngtBFDq2M5HQMMlkzFHFQVDN04XeZGjSxTM8ULAo3arHoDGYGsrEbhw9akI2zathwqjxAAbOmvWSHsxrIHsr4fFwewQO2ViWKauCECQ7IbO%2BeweFeN7EMtXBzLwg5wdZpBjiuk69Ro8RcPOb6SJIKIbBoc4tVu7U7l1%2B6HseB2kGeiCMhtT53hAD6bSgynAGd740LQX4/n%2BKEAcwxCwc2YGMAQUEwTuCGGMAyHNmhLl4Jh2HNrh%2BGEShxGkf2FFUTRGBrM2DFMcJbEcdxvH8YJjb9qJwiiOIUl87Jag7roARg6pHZzbTWlQDp7D6eaRkmWZLGWcOLZ2RkjmZfYrkuL54XvsEUwBbMIUFJkqU5O%2BUVWxVgXvoltQTMbeuE50EyOxbZVNDbfjO97ZsFTtizLHV74NU11YtW1HW8F1PX9YNZpg3svUfBoE1TTN6l7AtRBbX2prrY%2BsTLWYu2fVZo7%2BNnF3zq%2Bq69WYD2LmYKJPduKFvbYH37VZ30wL9TJJARgPA0%2B4SsGsycDUNOw42NZhZxNvCYPgRdEnofPiYL0jC0oosKbkAbUUkrNxz3nWcBBBHj8yqBUHs8%2Bp0vRgZ2vk3Tag/0V5sKue0TwLAQJCLAcRyRHQkA6LO85eorWXBoB0vUUG9XXKRZ6CddwcHekeQescfoQCQGPCeFAgZ/3LsQGeulup9QXsNZAo1xr9k3otRi9JIayH3pJQ%2BsgRbyWbIpUg58mCXzIjWOsN9E53wfgRPYz9X70NTiNMa2cf5l02ttauBDDpjikB8NuKJ5wrlumYM66CMqYOkTgvBNdNakTMDYvuuiFhmTSM4SQQA%3D)

While doing some C++ templates coding, I came accross something that compiles for Clang but failed for GCC, it's like something below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
 virtual void foo() {
   std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
 }
};

struct D:B {
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  D* d = new D();
  static_cast<B*>(d)->D::foo();
  delete d;
}
```

I want to know if the behavior of the code above well-defined according to C++ standard?

Comment: Why do you want to call `D::foo` after explicitly casting to `B*` ?

Comment: @wohlstad It's just a simple case for illustration, I'm actually doing some C++ complex templates coding and template type deduction happens to give me something like this.

Comment: Dup of [Can a method be referenced using a child class name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68926118/can-a-method-be-referenced-using-a-child-class-name-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

GCC is correct in this case, the program is ill formed. You cannot call a method of `D` from an instance of `B` directly without casting (in other words, undoing your initial upcast).

https://godbolt.org/z/b43zcWMqe

Both Clang and GCC *should* emit something to the effect of

```
<source>:14:26: error: 'D' is not a base of 'B'
   14 |   static_cast<B*>(d)->D::foo();
```

Comment: Is that true in this case? `D::foo()` is `B::foo` since `D` does not override it, and the compiler knows it. GCC casts `&D::foo` to `void (B::*)()` without issue (https://godbolt.org/z/cMexW65Yh), so maybe it's more about an implicit cast that can be done or not in this case?

Comment: What confuses me is that compiler knows `D::foo()` resolute  to  `B::foo()` here, and call `B::foo` via `B*` should be valid. If we define `D::foo()`, Clang gives compile error too, as expected.(https://godbolt.org/z/af9x6W8e3)

Comment: @konchy if using `->*` and assuming that `D::foo` expression is yielding a pointer to member, you'd be right. But neither is true here. To create a pointer to member, you have to use &. I guess it's bug in clang based on their way to resolve syntax of  method call for different base classes via hidden "implicit pointer semantics", it looks like they resolve `d->D::foo()` as `d->*&D::foo()`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'm actually doing qualified member function name lookup here, I dont know what standard says will happen when the left hand side class doesn't override the right side member function...

Comment: The pointer to member will be implicitly convertible in that case, to a B::* pointer. More like `(static_cast<B*>(d)->*&D::foo)();`.Operator precedence is sideways here. GCC will compile that if D doesn't have `foo`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Is that even true? A pointer to base-class member *is a* pointer to derived-class member, but not the other way around. That is, `&B::foo` can be converted implicitly to a `void (D::*)()`, but `&D::foo` cannot be converted implicitly to a `void (B::*)()`. (Unless the expression `&D::foo` is in this case already of type `void (B::*)()`; I do not know if that is the case, though.)